# anchor link over image

Tags: css

There is an image which has two anchor links over it. Clicking anywhere on the image will open an overlay to show the full sized image. Clicking on the buttons will open the facebook/twitter share dialogs.

What's happening here is, when the buttons are clicked, both the dialog and the overlay open up. How to stop the overlay from showing up when the anchor link is clicked.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<li style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="thumbPan">
      <img src="#" class="gallThumb">          
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="share_buttons">
      <a class="fshare" href="#" onclick="window.open(this.href, '',''); return false;"></a>
      <a class="tshare" href="#" onclick="window.open(this.href, '',''); return false;"></a>
  </div>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.share_buttons { position:absolute;}
.fshare, .tshare { float:left; display:block;background-repeat:no-repeat; 
                   background-position:left top; }
.fshare { background-image:url(../images/fshare.png);}
.tshare { background-image:url(../images/tshare.png); }
.thumbPan{ position:relative;}
.gallThumb{ width:100%; max-width:302px; height:auto;}
```

i tried setting .share_button as block but didnt work.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or add SO snippet? Looks like to be a z-index problem. But can't tell unless I'm playing around with it.

Comment: How do you open overlay?

Comment: Hmm..perhaps the overlay opens when the `li` is clicked?

Comment: It opens with some custom javascript

Comment: Try increasing z-index of those buttons..

Comment: Then that's what we need to see I suspect.

Comment: I tried z-index 10 for .fshare...but no luck....It seems , like I have to make it opaque or something ....

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but try anchor tag around img tag insted div like this.

```
<div class="thumbPan"> <a href="#"> <img src="#" class="gallThumb"/> </a> <span class="gallType video"></span> </div>
```

Also you havent closed img tag i know that is not the problem but it is good to close it.

Still if it doesnt work then try

```
z-index:99; 
z-index:98;
```

in the small images and

```
z-index:1;
```

In main image.

Comment: Try changing the position of thumbpan and share buttons.

Comment: Swap the positions of both i mean .sharebuttons{position:relative;} and .thumbpan{position:absolute;}.

Comment: That messed up  the whole images grid...:)